# JavaScript fade-in fade-out animation

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll, fadein, fadeout

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
  if(window.pageYOffset > 100)
  {
 document.getElementById('fade').style.opacity=1;
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById('fade').style.opacity=0;
  }
});
```

JavaScript fad-in fade-out animation with scrolling event or without using libraries API, only with logics

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use the CSS `transition` and `opacity` properties with a class that you toggle via JS to fade in/out an element:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  document.querySelector('#fade').classList.toggle('visible', window.pageYOffset > 100);
});
```

```css
#fade {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;

  /* only for this demo... */
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
}

#fade.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}

div {
  /* only for this demo... */
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div>Scroll down</div>
<div id="fade">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic example..

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<section>
    <div class="tile bottom-right"></div>
    <div class="tile bottom-right"></div>
    <div class="tile bottom-right"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
max-width:900px;
margin:0 auto;
}
.tile {
    height:400px;
    margin-top:40px;
    background:grey;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) rotate(-5deg) translateZ(0);
    transform: translateY(50px) rotate(-5deg) translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transition-delay: .3s;
    -o-transition-delay: .3s;
    transition-delay: .3s;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    -o-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    filter: grayscale(1);
}
.bottom-right.inView {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg) translateZ(0);
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg) translateZ(0);
}
.inView {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg) translateZ(0);
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg) translateZ(0);
}
section {
    padding:20px;
}
```

JS

```
let elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll(".tile");
console.log(elementsArray);
window.addEventListener('scroll', fadeIn ); 
function fadeIn() {
    for (var i = 0; i < elementsArray.length; i++) {
        var elem = elementsArray[i]
        var distInView = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top - window.innerHeight + 20;
        if (distInView < 0) {
            elem.classList.add("inView");
        } else {
            elem.classList.remove("inView");
        }
    }
}
fadeIn();
```

The animation is not made in JS. The animation is made in css. In the JS we remove or add the class. But we need the height of the screen the user is using with using the `var distInView = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top - window.innerHeight + 20;`. Please before copying the code read the code and try to understand what is happening..

Comment: is their another way to get height of screen using JavaScript code like with the used of inner. Height and outer. Height